# Meteor Http Paypal Adaptive Accounts

Tags: paypal, meteor

I'm trying to copy the example in this How-to guide [How-to guide](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-accounts/how-to-create-paypal-account-using-adaptive-accounts) but I always receive this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/CreateAccount. Origin http://my.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Could any provide me with a working example or any hints? Thank You!

This is my code:

```
Meteor.http.post("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/CreateAccount",{
        headers: {
            "X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS": "myemail@domain.com",
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": "myuserid",
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": "somepassword",
            "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": "thelongsignature",
            "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
            "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS": "192.0.2.0",
            "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
            "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON"
        },
        data: {
            accountType: "PERSONAL",
            name:{
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Doe"
            },
            address:{
                line1: "123 Main Street",
                city: "Sydney",
                state: "NSW",
                postalCode: "2000",
                countryCode: "AU",
                citizenshipCountryCode: "AU",
                contactPhoneNumber: "12345678",
                dateOfBirth: "1990-01-01Z",
                createAccountWebOptions:{
                    returnUrl: "http://my.domain.com/"
                },
                currencyCode: "AUD",
                emailAddress: "anotheremail@somedomain.com",
                preferredLanguageCode: "en_AU",
                registrationType: "Web",
                requestEnvelope:{
                    errorLanguage: "en_US"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    function(error,result){
        alert(error);
        alert(result.statuscode);
    })
```

Comment: I also noticed that i needed to add a } after countryCode: "AU" because thats where the address argument should stop.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this on the client side? It would be safer to run it from the server's end because your users can't see the credentials, additionally you shouldn't get the error if you requested the document from the server. Your web browser is blocking the request because its a [cross origin request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

server

```
Meteor.methods({
    'createaccount':function() {

    var result = Meteor.http.post("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/CreateAccount", {
        headers: {
        "X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS": "myemail@domain.com",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": "myuserid",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": "somepassword",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": "thelongsignature",
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
        "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS": "192.0.2.0",
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON"
        },
        data: {
        accountType: "PERSONAL",
        name:{
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe"
        },
        address:{
            line1: "123 Main Street",
            city: "Sydney",
            state: "NSW",
            postalCode: "2000",
            countryCode: "AU",
            citizenshipCountryCode: "AU",
            contactPhoneNumber: "12345678",
            dateOfBirth: "1990-01-01Z",
            createAccountWebOptions:{
                returnUrl: "http://my.domain.com/"
            },
            currencyCode: "AUD",
            emailAddress: "anotheremail@somedomain.com",
            preferredLanguageCode: "en_AU",
            registrationType: "Web",
            requestEnvelope:{
                errorLanguage: "en_US"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    return result;
});
```

client

```
Meteor.call('createaccount', function(error,result) { console.log(result); });
```

Note I've altered your request to a synchronous request so that it can return data to the client

Comment: AWESOME! Putting it in the server did the trick! :) I was going to put it in the server once I played around with it on the client. I'm using Cloud9 IDE so whenever i use console.log it doesn't display anything in the console unfortunately xD Thank you!!